# android second column returns no value

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a problem to create a table. If I try to get a value from the **second** column, android writes a empty space in the toast. But if I try to get a value from the **first** column, android writes the value of the column correctly. The query functions to write the first column and to write the second column are **equal**. So I think the Creation of the Table is the problem. But look yourself:

```
    public SQLiteDatabase tabelleerstellen(){
    SQLiteDatabase leveldatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("leveldata.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    leveldatabase.setVersion(1);
    final String CREATE_TABLE_LEVEL =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_level ("
                    + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "ME1 TEXT, "
                    + "ME2 TEXT, "
                    + "ME3 TEXT, "
                    + "ME4 TEXT, "
                    + "ME5 TEXT, "
                    + "ME6 TEXT, "
                    + "ME8 TEXT, "
                    + "GESCHAFFT INTEGER);";
    leveldatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LEVEL);
    return leveldatabase;
}
public void tester(SQLiteDatabase leveldata){
    ContentValues cursortester = new ContentValues();
    cursortester.put("ME2","25");
    leveldata.insert("tbl_level",null,cursortester);
    String[] testerpr = {"ME2"};
    Cursor testerprüfen = leveldata.query("tbl_level",testerpr,null,null, null, null,null,null);
    testerprüfen.moveToFirst();
    String dada = testerprüfen.getString(testerprüfen.getColumnIndex("ME2"));
    Toast testertoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dada,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    testertoast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following things:

1. Please make sure the table is up to date .. so try to call `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_level;` and recreate the table.
2. If you run a test make sure the table is completely empty ... so delete everything at the beggining of the test.
3. If the table can contain elements during the test then make sure you check the last inserted element. Please note that calling `testerprüfen.moveToFirst();` moves the cursor to the first row in the table so checking that row every time is even if the table contains 50 elements is not a good thing. In this case you either use a sorting option in your query of uese `while (testerprüfen != null && testerprüfen.moveToNext()) {// Your code here}`

All in all I think your problem is that you already inserted more that one element in the able but you always check only the first element (with `testerprüfen.moveToFirst();`). Please not that there is a `cursor.moveToLast()` method that you can also call. This method moves the cursor to the last row in the table.